# Picasa Embed Gallery + Custom jQuery UI slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, scroll, gallery, picasa

I am trying to create a tool that scrolls a  whem dynamic items from from Picasa.
Picasa allows a nested file option which means that new items are being loaded over and over as the user navigates through the file system.

I want to create a a custom scroll bar for this div when necessary.
I have found someone working version of what I would like to do, but cannot get it to work with my situation. 
Basically I need the function to check for the scroll bar every time new content loads, or on click of a specific element.

If someone could help me integrate this plugin I would be very grateful. 
The plugin is very well documented but I am still a jQuery noob, so I am not having much luck.

Thanks.

---

jQuery UI slider plugin:
http://www.simonbattersby.com/blog/vertical-scrollbar-using-jquery-ui-slider/

Embed Picasa Snippet:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#picasagallery").EmbedPicasaGallery('andreagerstmann',{
        loading_animation: 'css/loading.gif',
        size: '190',
        msg_loading_list :  'Just one moment please',
        msg_back :   'Back'
    });
});
```

In Progress Copy:
http://andreagerstmann.com/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

Patrick

Does this variant of the slider give you what you want:

http://www.simonbattersby.com/demos/vertical_scrollbar_demo_7_addcontent.htm

In this variant the slider code is wrapped into a setSlider() function - so you'd just need to call this function once your Picasa code is completed.

Simon

Answer (score 0):

I did this a while back using:

Load large dataset with infinite scroll in ASP.NET (VBASPNETInfiniteLoading)
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/VBASPNETInfiniteLoading-10c3f379

original article:
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/load-content-while-scrolling-with-jquery/

working example: 
http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/dnspinger/

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/Site.css" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"></script>



    $(document).ready(function () {

       function lastPostFunc() {
           $('#divPostsLoader').html('<img src="images/bigLoader.gif">');

           //send a query to server side to present new content
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "Default.aspx/Foo",
               data: "{}",
               contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function (data) {

                   if (data != "") {
                       $('.divLoadData:last').after(data.d);
                   }
                   $('#divPostsLoader').empty();
               }

           })
       };

       //When scroll down, the scroller is at the bottom with the function below and fire
    the lastPostFunc function
       $(window).scroll(function () {
           if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
               lastPostFunc();
           }
       });

    });
```